# How to Make a New Column in a Data Set with Values Corresponding to a Separate Data Set

Tags: r, loops, date

I have two different csv files, one is called `CA_Storms` and one is called `CA_adj`. `CA_Storms` has many start and end dates/times for storm events (in one column), and `CA_adj` has a `DateTime` column that includes many thousand dates/times. I want to see if any of the dates/times in `CA_adj` correspond with any of the storm events in `CA_Storms`. To do this, I am trying to make a new column in `CA_adj` titled `Storm_ID` that will identify which storm it corresponds with based on the storm start and end times/dates in `CA_Storms`.

This is the process I have currently undergone:

```
#Make a value to which the csv files are attached
CA_Storms <- read.csv(file = "CA_Storms.csv", header = TRUE,       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
CA_adj <- read.csv(file = "CA_adj.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors

#strptime function (do this for both data sets)
CA_adj$DateTime1 <- strptime(CA_adj$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
CA_Storms$Start.time1 <- strptime(CA_Storms$Start.time, format = "%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M")
CA_Storms$End.time1 <- strptime(CA_Storms$End.time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

#Make a new column into CA_adj that says Storm ID. Have it by 
#default hold NAs.
CA_adj$Storm_ID <- NA

#Write a which statement to see if it meets the conditions of greater than
#or equal to start time or less than or equal to end time. Put this through a 
#for loop to apply it to every row within CA_adj$DateTime1

    for (i in nrow(CA_adj$DateTime1))
    { 
      CA_adj$DateTime1[which(CA_adj$DateTime1 >= CA_Storms$Start.time1 | CA_adj$DateTime1 <= CA_Storms$End.time1), "Storm_ID"]
    }
```

This is not giving me any errors, but it's also not replacing any of the values in the `Storm_ID` column that I have made. In my Global Environment under "Values" it now just says: `i is NULL(empty)`. I am pretty sure what's missing is an `i` within the for loop, but I do not know where to put it. I also think the other issue is that it doesn't know what value to replace the NA's in the `Storm_ID` column with. I would like it to replace the NA's with the correct Storm ID that corresponds with the Storm dates (in `CA_Storms$Start.time1` and in `CA_Storms$End.Time1)`. For Dates/Times within `CA_adj` that do not apply to a storm date, I'd just want it to continue to say NA.

Any guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to R, and I've been trying to teach it to myself, which can make figuring out how to do these things on my own a bit difficult.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a look at the lubridate package.  It will let you create time/date intervals which can then be tested against a specific time/date by   %within% .  Your code should be simpler.

You do need to use the loop index and you also need to make an assignment to CA_adj$StormID.  I'm not certain if you could also have multiple CA_adj entries in a CA_Storms interval.

```
# make a lubridate interval in CA_Storms
# make CA_DateTime a lubridate 
# or stick with the longer code...

# loop through all CA_adj

for (i in nrow(CA_adj)) {
  CA_adj$StormID[i] <- CA_Storms$StormID[CA_adj$DateTime %within% CA_Storms$interval]
}
```